# Не могу убрать расстояние между блоками(выделено,мешают фиолетовые границы)

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из классов на изображении max-width:100%; height:auto;
пробовал вручную указать размер-поддается изменению лишь высота,а мне как раз нужна ширина

Comment: ммммм да....   щас,  карты таро раскину, может и отвечу........

Comment: фиолетовые границы это паддинги, Вы бы хоть css привели